# Convert Num to Double in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghc

I know about the existence of `fromRational`, `fromInteger` and `fromIntegral`.
But is there a more generic function to convert any `Num` to the `Double` type?
I'm also aware of the fact that `Num` is a set of types, and possibly that comes with limitations of how to use it.
But it is possible?
Something like:

```
fromNum::(Num a) => a -> Double
```

And preferably, without installing any additional packages.

Comment: A potential problem is that any Haskell programmer may create some new instance of the `Num` class. Class `Num` is an **open** set of types. What could the `fromNum` library function do, if faced with an instance of a sort completely unforeseen by its creators ?

Comment: How do you convert `Complex Double` to `Double`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is absolutely not a way to do this, and for a very good reason. `Num` is a generic type designed to be used for anything vaguely "addable" and "multiply-able". You can *very loosely* think of it as a [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics))<sup>[1]</sup>. This means that things like vectors, points, and matrices are `Num`. And there's no reasonable, canonical way to convert a [`Matrix a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bed-and-breakfast-0.5/docs/Numeric-Matrix.html) into a `Double`.

You've already noted that there are several ways to get to `Double` from more specific typeclasses like `Integral`.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Yes, `fromInteger` is also on `Num`. That's largely considered a misfeature and libraries doing things with matrices usually just provide an awkward default implementation.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, I thought that `Num` was a superset of `Complex`, interesting.
Is there a sort of `fromReal` function (something like `fromReal::Real -> Double`)?

Comment: @OtávioAugustoSilva `fromReal = fromRational . toRational`?

Comment: @OtávioAugustoSilva `Complex` is one of the types in the `Num` class, so in that sense it's a "superset". But that's exactly why when you have a value of an unknown `Num` type you can't assume you can do operations on it that you would do on `Complex`; it's a **super**set, so it includes other things that might not support all the properties of `Complex`.

Comment: @amalloy that already exists as `realToFrac`

Comment: I disagree that `fromInteger` is a misfeature for the `Num` class. Instead, it's misappropriation to instantiate `Num` for things like matrices. Matrices _are not numbers_. In particular, they also don't have a sensible implementation for `*` – unless you count the Hadamard product, but that's hardly the natural product, _matrix multiplication_ is. But that doesn't have a `*`-ey type, it's rather a category-composition type. Instead, the correct type class for matrices is [vector space](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space).

Comment: The answer is still correct; but a better example is good old `Complex`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout vector-space is great, yes; I wish more people used it. I think the misfeature is not specifically `fromInteger`, but in forcibly tying "things that can be added to produce the same type" to "things that can be multiplied to produce the same type" and to "things that can be represented in source code as integer literals". All three of those concepts are useful for types where one or both of the others don't make sense. With the benefit of hindsight, they should all be separate classes (optionally with a class like `Num` to bring them together with superclass constraints).

Comment: @Ben yes, in hindsight many things should have been done different. But I'm also not sure whether a more fine-grained `Num` hierarchy would really be desirable: numbers are after all basic stuff that should be made as little confusing as possible for beginners. IMO it's just fine to keep `+` as the number-specific addition operator, and then have `^+^` for the more general case. If that gets too verbose in some application, one can always make a custom prelude such that `+` refers to the `AdditiveGroup` version instead of the `Num` one.